# ArcPy SelectByLayerAttribute_management does not select when provided with path of file

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute

I've been doing some experimentation with SelectByLayerAttribute, and I've noticed that it does not select anything when provided with the path of a feature layer (e.g. 'C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ProjectName\test.gdb\Electric_substations')

It only works with layers that are sourced from the Contents pane (ArcGIS Pro Script tool)

[image: using input from contents pane]

`in_substation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)`

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_substation , "NEW_SELECTION", where_cond)`

The only solution that I can think of now is to add it to the Contents pane using
`m.addDataFromPath('C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ProjectName\test.gdb\Electric_substations')` then using that as the input somehow.

If I had a layer located at the path 'C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ProjectName\test.gdb\Electric_substations', could I convert it to a format where SelectByLayerAttribute would accept it without adding it to the contents pane using addDataFromPath?

Comment: Layer functions operate on `Layer` objects. A source path is not a valid `Layer` because it doesn't have a selection set property (which moots the purpose of `SelectLayerByAttribute`)

Comment: Try Select tool, it works on feature classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool, Select Layer by Attribute only works on **layers**. A **layer**, is *different* than the featureclass or item on disk. The layer is either virtual, or resides in the app (ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro, etc). Think of the layer like a *view* of the data. You need to put the selection (what the tool is doing), on the *layer*.

I'm not entirely sure of your workflow - it sounds like you're working with a tool, inside the app, but you are *not* using layers. (Maybe there is a good reason for this, but typically in the app, you'd just use a layer, something added to your map). Anyways, you can still use a item on disk (featureclass). Instead of using Select Layer by Attribute, make use of [Make Feature Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm). It will "turn a featureclass into a layer". It has the added benefit of a `where` parameter, so the tool does two things at once.